# How to identify the data bytes used for CRC(checksum) in an USB ISO-Transfer?

Tags: c, usb, libusb

I'm using libusb to get data in real time from an USB audio device. My Max Packet Size is of 196 bytes. I know that 4 of that bytes are added for the checksum. I want to identify the bytes used to the checksum so I can store only the usefull data of the transfer but  I have some doubts:

1) Are these bytes added at the beginning or at the end of the packet?

2) Do these bytes have a reserved value?

3) In case of losing some data bytes in the transfer. What considerations should I use for the bytes used for the checksum?

EDIT 1

I have these doubts because my specific device has an Interface and alt-setting that works with a sample rate of 48 KHz, 2 channels, 16 bits depth and with a Max Packet Size of 196 bytes.

So there are 48 samples * 2 of two channels * 2 bytes = 192 bytes

So then my packets should be of 192 bytes but when I set my device to work with that interface and alt-setting I start to receive packets of 196 bytes.
The corresponding interface and alt-setting for the OUT ISO Endpoint works at a sample rate of 48 KHz, 2 channels, 16 bits depth and with a Max Packet Size of 192 bytes.

4) If these bytes are not from the checksum why are these bytes being added?

Comment: You should be able to get this information from the protocol specification. If you don't have one, you will have to reverse-engineer it.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I know that 4 of that bytes are added for the checksum

> > Wrong. CRC is 2 bytes for data packet and 5 bits for token packet. Also CRC is never stored/forwarded in/to the user buffer. It gets stripped by the controller during verification of the CRC. So you are not going to see the CRC at all.
> >     But if you still want to see the CRC, attach a USB packet analyzer and have a look at the trace.

1) Are these bytes added at the beginning or at the end of the packet?

> > 2 bytes are added at the end.

2) Do these bytes have a reserved value?

> > No. Its calculated based on the content of the data packet

3) In case of losing some data bytes in the transfer. What considerations should I use for the bytes used for the checksum?

> > If you are losing some bytes after CRC is already calculated, you are going to get USB transaction error (CRC mismatch from the host). The same transaction will be retried by the host.

PS - I assumed you are using high speed device

Comment: I know that 16 bits are used for the CRC but I think I'm getting 4 bytes because I'm receiving data for an Isochronous Stereo Endpoint. So 2 bytes are from first channel and the other 2 bytes are from the second channel.

Comment: Ok got your point but CRC is used by your host controller for verification and based on the result it will decide whether to consider it as a good or bad packet. If its good packet, the host will store the data in the transfer descriptor (EHCI) or  transfer ring (XHCI). So no CRC is stored in your buffer.

Comment: Also I think 2 bytes from one channel and 2 bytes from other will be packed in one data packet and sent across the link. CRC is per packet and not per channel. Ultimately its one endpoint sending one packet at a time. So one CRC per data packet.

Comment: Well you have a good point. My doubt started because the ISO-In has a max packet size of 196 bytes but the corresponding ISO-Out has a max packet size of 192. I can't find where I read that those extra bytes are used for the checksum.

Comment: When you say "ISO-In has a max size of 196 bytes", are you talking about your specific device or in general? If you are referring it for isochronous endpoints in general then that will be incorrect as the max size is 1024 bytes for HS USB devices. Also OUT endpoint has the same max size. Check the specification.

Comment: I'm talking about my specific device. It has an Interface and alt-setting that works with a sample rate of 48 KHz, 2 channels, 16 bits depth and with a Max Packet Size of 196 bytes. So there are 48 samples * 2 of two channels * 2 bytes = 192 bytes, then my packets should be of 192 bytes. But when I read my data most of the time I get packets of 196 bytes.

Comment: Ok. You can connect a packet analyzer anyway. But I really doubt that its CRC because that defeats the whole purpose of error detection in host controller hardware. Sending the CRC to SW layer can only mean that Host controller wants to do CRC validation in SW layer which does not happen in the host controller driver as far as I know.